# Should I include my first job that is not relevant in my CV?

Tags: professionalism, resume

I need some advice on this.

So I was recently graduated last year. I work for a fmcg company as a supply chain analyst. I have a referral that introduce me to a marketing job in a market research industry.

So should I include the last job? I have past experience as part time market surveyor and I would definitely like to include in it but it was during my college time. How should I list it? In a chronological order? Cause I might look like a huge gap if I don't include my last job.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add it. One of the things hiring managers scan for are indeed gaps in your CV. By not being transparent about the timeline, you either create the impression that you are sloppy or that you have something to hide.

Even if the actual job contents/responsibilities are not relevant to your new role, there is a lot of meta experience worth discussing:
How did you deal with co workers and management, what were the things you liked best or disliked most about the environment, etc. These are still useful areas of conversation during the hiring process

Answer (score 0):

At this stage in your career, yes, it makes sense to add it. It will show experience - and there will be skills from it that will show additional value to a recruiter.

Further down your career it may make less sense (eg if you have had 8 jobs over 20 years, and the first one is unrelated - I'd suggest you could ignore it)